# Unable to divide two column in quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, tableau-api, amazon-quicksight

I have made two calculated field in my quicksight anaysis - `'Correct Prediction'` and `'Total Count'`

Formulas used for above two calculated are -

```
Correct Prediction = ifelse({best_exp_rank} <= 15,1,0)
Total Count = count({best_exp_rank})
```

Now I made a pivot table and kept the above columns as values(`Correct Prediction(Sum)`, `Total Count(custom)`).

When I'm trying to make a third column which is (`Correct Prediction/Total Count`) as a calculated field.
I face the following error.

> mismatched aggregation. custom aggregations can’t contain both
>   aggregate "`count`" and non-aggregated fields
>   “count("best_exp_rank")”, in any combination.

Can anyone please help me with this problem? Please comment if you need any extra information

Answer (score 1):

Add a calculated field like -

```
(sum({Correct Prediction}) / {Total Count}) * 100
```